# How to pass file extracted data into an array to a print function using ostream&? (C++)

Tags: c++, multidimensional-array, struct, pass-by-reference, iostream

I'm trying to use two functions -

1. read data from a text file and store it into an array formatted from a struct
2. print array data by ostream&

```
const int maxRows =20;
//3 columns across

struct someThing{
string a;
int b;
int c;
}

void readFile (someThing arr[], int x) {
    //do stuff
    //open file...
    //loop 
}

void printArray (ostream&, someThing thing){
    
     //?? I am not sure what to here...

     //cout <<thing.a <<','<<thing.b <<','<<thing.c <<endl;

     for (int i = 0; i < maxRows; i++){
        cout << thing[i];

}
```

text file formatted as below.

```
thing1 15.30 48
thing2 20.15 78
thing3 108.23 56
```

etc....for 20 rows

Technically there is still an enum class but I will have to work that back in but basics first.

I have tried:
-using `ostream& os` then `os<<thing[i];` I just get operator overload issues and reference errors.
-as many key words as I can think of.
-I went through the cplusplus forums.
-read my C++ book that made me more confused.
-I couldn't find much to help with the enum class so I took it out.

```
   switch (thing.size){
        case thingType:: S: "Small"; break;
        case thingType::M: "Medium"; break;
        case thingType::L: "Large"; break;
    }
```

Comment: `ostream& operator<<(ostream& o, const someThing& thing) { o << thing.a << ',' << thing.b << ',' << thing.c; return o; }`

Comment: It feels to me that you're trying to do too much at once. Take a few steps back, perhaps take some rest, eat dinner, sleep. Then tomorrow, start all over, by dividing the problem into smaller sub-problems. Divide them into smaller and smaller parts, until there's nothing that can be split or divided further. Then implement each small and now very simple problem one by one, building and testing each in isolation. When you put it all together, the larger and more complex problems should be solved, until you have a finished program.

Comment: It would help if the code snippets were consistent with one another. Your switch statement has nothing to do with any types defined in the first code example. It also does absolutely nothing. If you are having errors, you should show the errors and the related code. Even better, produce a [mre] to demonstrate the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You should not use "C" style arrays, C++'s resizable array `std::vector`. Also file IO in C++ is usually handled through streams.
Wherever you can you also should use `range based for loops` instead of index based ones (to avoid going out of bounds of your arrays by accident).

All in all it would look something like this :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <vector> // don't use "C" style arrays like you do this is C++ after all

// don't use `using namespace std;` 
//const int maxRows =20; No with std::vector we can read any number of lines

struct someThing
{
    std::string a;
    int b;
    int c;
};

// In C++ when dealing with files you might as well 
// generalize to streams.
// So create overloads for streaming someThing from and to streams

std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& is, someThing& st)
{
    is >> st.a >> st.b >> st.c;
    return is;
}

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const someThing& st)
{
    os << st.a << " " << st.b << " " << st.c;
    return os;
}

// Now we use the power of the C++ resizable array
// std::vector to load data from a stream (line by line)
std::vector<someThing> Load(std::istream& is)
{
    std::vector<someThing> things;
    someThing thing;
    std::string line;

    while (getline(is, line))
    {
        std::istringstream iss(line);
        iss >> thing;
        things.push_back(thing);
    }
   
    return things;
}

// Saving is now the same as writing each thing to a stream
void Save(std::ostream& os, const std::vector<someThing>& things)
{
    for (const auto& thing : things)
    {
        os << thing << "\n";
    }
}

// simulate a file 
// when doing testing don't rely on your file system
// just simulate the file in memory using a stringstream
std::stringstream is
{
    "thing1 15.30 48\n"
    "thing2 20.15 78\n"
    "thing3 108.23 56\n"
};

int main()
{
    // load your things from any stream
    // you can replace this with a std::ifstream
    // in production code
    auto things = Load(is);
    
    // save to std::cout for testing 
    // replace with std::ofstream in production code
    Save(std::cout, things);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help.  Is it even possible to do something like this with C style arrays? The more I read about C/C++ arrays it's like I'm miss understanding the question from class but it said to not use vectors.

Comment: There is no "C/C++" really there isn't. The fact that "C" style arrays are still around is because of backward compatibility with "C". Using `std::vector` is THE way to do this in C++. std::vector is not the advanced way. What you are asking for is complicated (with new and delete[]) and will result in code with more bugs.

Comment: Since your teacher asking you to use "C" style arrays let him watch [Stop teaching "C"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YnWhqhNdYyk) and read the [C++ core guidelines](https://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines) and ask him to update his training materials.

Comment: An array is simple a set of memory cells in a row. In "C" what looks like an array is only a pointer to the first cell and the notation arr[i], is just a shorthand for "go to the first element using the pointer and move `i` steps ahead. "C" also happily lets you run past the end of the array. So if you need a bigger array you need to make a new bigger one (copy content over)  and delete the old one. And this is the part that vector manages for you automatically. But sure it can still be done  with "C" style arrays.

Comment: I would not mind talking to your teacher about not being allowed to use std::vector ;)
It should be easy for him to make a small exercise to show that whole memory allocation  thing only once (decoupled from file IO) and then switch to using std::vector